# CheckStyle rules for Java Code Conventions from 1997

Tags: java, checkstyle, sun-coding-conventions

Is there a CheckStyle rule file that checks against the [Java Code Conventions from September 12, 1997](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)?

Comment: Isn't the default Sun style offered by Checkstyle according to the conventions you referenced?

Comment: AFAIK, it hasn't changed significantly since then. Most style checkers support this by default. If you use a pretty formatter (in most IDEs) it fixes many of these issues for you automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [checkstyle homepage](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), it contains an example configuration file *supporting the Sun Code Conventions*. It does not say how *supporting* is defined, but it links to exactly the same document as you in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just download checkstyle from sourceforge.net and find `sun_checks.xml` inside